# Python: ошибки при обращения к Google Sheets

Tags: python, google-spreadsheet

Подскажите пожалуйста, что не так делаю, почему в этом коде:

```python
import httplib2
import apiclient.discovery
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
    
CREDENTIALS_FILE = 'fastpoverka-v2-08eef534af66.json'  # Имя файла с закрытым ключом, вы должны подставить свое
    
# Читаем ключи из файла
credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(CREDENTIALS_FILE, ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'])
        
httpAuth = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http()) # Авторизуемся в системе
service = apiclient.discovery.build('sheets', 'v4', http = httpAuth) # Выбираем работу с таблицами и 4 версию API
        
spreadsheetId = '19eU_PwEk-zDDKkdPidRTLfi1hpnBbJVHOKwGTLU9X_c' # сохраняем идентификатор файла

print('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/' + spreadsheetId)
        
# Получаем список листов, их Id и название
spreadsheet = service.spreadsheets().get(spreadsheetId=spreadsheetId).execute()
sheetList = spreadsheet.get('sheets')
for sheet in sheetList:
    print(sheet['properties']['sheetId'], sheet['properties']['title'])
        
sheetId = sheetList[0]['properties']['sheetId']
```

Выдаёт такие ошибки:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/turremail.ru/PycharmProjects/documets/test.py", line 17, in <module>
    spreadsheet = service.spreadsheets().get(spreadsheetId=spreadsheetId).execute()
  File "/Users/turremail.ru/PycharmProjects/documets/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/googleapiclient/_helpers.py", line 130, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/turremail.ru/PycharmProjects/documets/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/googleapiclient/http.py", line 856, in execute
    raise HttpError(resp, content, uri=self.uri)
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 403 when requesting https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/19eU_PwEk-zDDKkdPidRTLfi1hpnBbJVHOKwGTLU9X_c?alt=json returned "The caller does not have permission">
```

Спасибо.

Comment: причина же английским по белому написана - у вас нет прав.

Comment: У этого файла я владелец - вроде выше прав нет?!

Comment: ну да, прям так и написано: "The caller does not have permission". Колдунство какое-то

Comment: Ссылка на скрин с правами доступа: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1sKYq1aMzf_WWggOo70C1PoPYzj7lDcDU/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

Большое спасибо за помощь. Разобрался - нужно было дать доступ к файлу сервисному аккаунту и всё заработало. Ссылка на скрин: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bSZYP1dBkkQrHsZGsEhrF82Llc_EPlEM/view?usp=sharing

Comment: А, ну да, хотел я ещё про сервисный эккаунт написать, но толком не помнил что там и как

Comment: Спасибо, за помощь.